# Drupal 8 cookie cache issue

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

I have a drupal 8 site which set a cookie value 'Drupal_visitor_country' dynamically. But this value is getting cached and I am not able to retrieve it properly during page refresh.

I am using this value on theme_preprocess_menu function but it always returns cached cookie value instead of actual value. Is there any way i can overcome this situation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For me [Middleware API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/middleware-api/overview) did the trick. See below.

**Did not work:** Tried to use [KernelEvents](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-kernel%21KernelEvents.php/class/KernelEvents/8.2.x) - they did not fire upon page request. `KernelEvents::REQUEST` did fire upon assets requests.

**Did not work:** Tried to abuse `services.yml`, but found that I actually can not exclude a page here.

```
renderer.config:
  required_cache_contexts: ['languages:language_interface', 'theme', 'user.permissions', ... ]
```

**Did not work:** Then I tried to create my own CacheContext. Found out that it also does not provide a way for exclusion. at best you can generate unique cache for every load for a specific node, but that would kill cache. [How to recognize, discover and create?](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts) Also: [CacheContextInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21Context%21CacheContextInterface.php/interface/CacheContextInterface/8.2.x)

**Did work:** [Middleware API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/middleware-api/overview). It is executed before Drupal caching.
Best is to start off from Page Cache:

- [page_cache.services.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21page_cache%21page_cache.services.yml/8.6.x)
- [class PageCache](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21page_cache%21src%21StackMiddleware%21PageCache.php/class/PageCache/8.6.x).

Be aware that during Middleware processing Drupal may not be fully bootstrapped and some functionality may not be there.

Thank you Mario Vercellotti for pointing me to right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Use `EventSubscriber: $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onRequest'];`

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\kvantstudio\EventSubscriber\KvantstudioEventSubscriber.
 */

namespace Drupal\kvantstudio\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Event Subscriber KvantstudioEventSubscriber.
 */
class KvantstudioEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Code that should be triggered on event specified 
   */
  public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
     if (!isset($_COOKIE['Drupal_visitor_userHash'])) {  
        $uuid = \Drupal::service('uuid');
        user_cookie_save(['userHash' => 'user-' . $uuid->generate()]);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events = [];       
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onRequest'];
    return $events;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have similar scenario, but KernelEvents::REQUEST events seem to be executed only on non-cached pages, so its not helpful for me.